# Sorting WP Query results

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, advanced-custom-fields

I am running a user query on my wordpress site to list sales reps. Basically I have a page listing all users that are in the 'sales reps' role, and using jQuery to hide/show them based on a state dropdown selector.

In any state where a territory isn't covered, I need to list the corporate office as one of the results. The corporate office is listed as a sales rep, and its ID is 11. The issue I'm having is that I always need the corporate office to list last as the last result.

The territory covered by the corporate office changes from state to state, so I can't run the query then just throw the corporate office at the end. It needs to list meta data that is specific to the selected state, so it has to be part of the query.

Here's what I have so far:

```
            $args = array();
            $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'SalesRep' ) );

            if ( ! empty( $user_query->get_results() ) ) {
                foreach ( $user_query->get_results() as $user ) { ?>
                    <div class="rep hide" data-category="
                    <?php
                        if( have_rows('states', 'user_'.$user->ID) ):
                            while ( have_rows('states', 'user_'.$user->ID) ) : the_row();
                                echo the_sub_field('state', 'user_'.$user->ID) . ' ';
                            endwhile;
                        else :
                        endif;
                    ?> ">
                        <p><strong><?php echo $user->display_name;?></strong>
                        <?php
                        $has_area = false;
                        if( have_rows('states', 'user_'.$user->ID) ):
                            while ( have_rows('states', 'user_'.$user->ID) ) : the_row();
                            echo '<span class="stateID" data-category="'.get_sub_field('state', 'user_'.$user->ID).'">';
                            the_sub_field('area', 'user_'.$user->ID);


                              echo '</span>';
                            endwhile;
                        else :
                        endif; ?>
                        <a href="mailto:<?php echo $user->user_email;?>"><?php echo $user->user_email;?><br />
                        <a href="tel:1-<?php the_field('phone_number', 'user_'.$user->ID)?>">
                        <?php the_field('phone_number', 'user_'.$user->ID)?></a>
                    </div>
                <?php }
            } else {
                echo 'No Sales Reps Found.';
            } ?>
```

This code works great, but I am at a loss as to how to push the corporate office to the end. Do I need to use uasort? Or should I look for the post->ID and unset it if it == 11?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks much

Comment: Could we get sample desired output? It'll help me help you. And/or just current output - the movement of the corp office to the bottom is pretty clear

Comment: Sure! So for example, California has 2 sales reps, and the rest of the territory is covered by the corporate office. So when the I select that state with the dropdown selector, the corporate office lists first (alphabetically).

So each time I use the select field, I would want it to display as such:  
  
John Doe  
Bay Area   
555.555.5555   
  
Jane Doe  
Los Angeles  
555.555.5555  
  
Corporate Office  
All other territories  
555.555.5555  

I hope that's what you meant by desired output. If I can make things any clearer please let me know. And thank you for your help.

Comment: Probably better solutions but you could always add an ID to the parent div, then reorder the list with JQuery while you're determining which to show/hide. I was going to butcher the JQuery from memory, but use a tmp variable to store the div with id == 11, delete it, and append the tmp back onto the bottom of the parent element. I don't particularly like it, but it should work

Answer (score 0):

If you have metadata associated with the SalesRep role, then you can add meta to the user query and sort results based on that meta value. The first item in the Examples section shows adding meta to the query
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

There's an Order & Orderby Parameters section that shows how to sort retrieved users with orderby.

Comment: This is great except OP needs a custom ordering that won't fit any predetermined sort order in every case. At least that's my impression.

Comment: Correct, every state is different. Some states dont list the corporate office at all. Listing by meta would work in some cases, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this turned out to be a bit easier than I anticipated. I added a metafield of 'corporate_office' then assigned a selector to each user. It defaults to no for all users, and yes for the corporate office. Then I modified my query to orderby the metafield in ASC order. Solved. Thanks to everyone for their suggestions.